# How to return a list of values through recursion in java?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, binary-tree, inorder

Returning a single value through recursion works just fine. But what if I want to return a list of values that recursion goes through each call. Here's my code.

```
public void inOrder(Node focusNode) {

  /* ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); */

  if ( focusNode != null) {

    inOrder(focusNode.getLeftNode());
    System.out.println(focusNode);
    /*  tempList.add(focusNode.getElement()); */
    inOrder(focusNode.getRightNode());

  }

/*  int[] elems = new int[tempList.toArray().length];
  int i = 0;
  for ( Object o : tempList.toArray()) 
    elems[i++] = Integer.parseInt(o.toString()); */

  //return tempList;
}
```

printing values while traversing through gives the expected output. But storing those values is not working. It only returns with a single value in a list. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just pass in a reference to an array list along with your starting node? After your inOrder method runs, you'll have an ordered series of values that you can use as you please.

```
// method signature changed
public void inOrder(Node focusNode, ArrayList vals) {

    /* ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); */

    if ( focusNode != null) {
        // args changed here
        inOrder(focusNode.getLeftNode(), vals);
        // adding node to array list rather than dumping to console
        vals.add(focusNode);
    /*  tempList.add(focusNode.getElement()); */
        inOrder(focusNode.getRightNode());
}
```

Comment: **Thank you so much !**  This is much better way than returning a list. `:)` One more question, does java also passes variables through reference?

Comment: @GauravP Please: if you are able to write such a question here ... then you are also able to put those same strings into a search engine. SO is not "programming school" where teachers explain things to you that are documented a zillion times. This is not meant to be rude; it is just what this site is about ... or not, in this case. In other words: you are expected to do "prior research"; and especially when you are a beginner: please understand that probably any "theoretical" question you can come up with ... was asked here before. And answered. Multiple. Times.

Comment: @GhostCat I completely get that. Apologies for that. It won't happen again.

Comment: @GauravP If my answer addressed your question, please click the checkmark on the left side to let future readers know what worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: @MarsAtomic worked? totally. It saved my 230 lines of code which was completely dependent on this sorted values. _Thank You again_ (Even if stackoverflow suggest me to avoid)!

Comment: @GauravP Glad it helped. I think what you were being asked to avoid is asking about whether Java passes by reference or value, since that's easier to search. Good luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: @MarsAtomic no, no, I didn't mean that. Even I didn't take it any wrong. I totally understand what I shouldn't post. What I meant was that when you hover over _add comment_ it says `avoid things like +1 and thanks`